# WebAuthn not registering/validating on oneplus devices

Tags: google-play-services, webauthn, passkey

I was trying to implement WebAuthn in my web application when I encountered a weird issue. WebAuthn is working fine, I'm able to register with every mobile device using scan QR code and verify later except for oneplus devices.

My guess is it has something to do with Google play services or how OxygenOS handles the authentication using fingerprint.

For these experiments I have used Oneplus Nord and Oneplus 7 running android 13 and 14.

I have tried these on [webauthn.io](https://webauthn.io) and tried all the combinations of setting possible to get around this issue.

Observation -

1. Go to webauthn.io
2. Enter username
3. Click Register
4. Select iPhone, iPad or Android device
5. Scan QR code in QR code app or google on OnePlus device
6. Device shows fingerprint but web resolves to Timeout or operation cancelled message.

Expected behaviour would be that it should wait for fingerprint authentication or password and register if success else show error.

Comment: Getting same thing with LG phones. Super annoying, as I was up until 2am trying to figure out what went wrong. Oddly it had been somehow working. Not any more. Tested same software with Samsung and works fine.

Comment: Similar on Oppo phones. Others have noted, according to a web search, that the pin/fingerprint check is the point when it fails

Answer (score 1):

Does the OnePlus device have Google Play Services? If not, then there simply might not be any passkey implementation.

You do say that "Device shows fingerprint" however, which suggests that perhaps something is happening? I'd need to see a logcat to be able to say more.

Comment: Getting same issue as OP, always at fingerprint check as roaming authenticator, on LG and Oppo phones, not Samsung (the ones I have available). Platform authenticator works.

Comment: Thanks to a user who was able to provide a logcat from an affected device we have identified a behaviour with OnePlus's BiometricPrompt implementation that caused problems. A fix will be available in Play Services in the coming weeks.

Comment: doesnt work on lg or oppo either. Posted a logcat in another so issue. Seems various manufacturers have the same problem